# PHP pthreads: Difference between Threaded and Stackable

Tags: php, pthreads

I am confused as to what's the difference between the two classes [`Threaded`](http://php.net/manual/class.threaded.php) and `Stackable` in the [pthreads](http://php.net/manual/book.pthreads.php) PHP extension.

The PHP manual pages don't mention `Stackable`, but it exists and many texts about pthreads mention this class; for example:

- [Recycling Contexts](http://pthreads.org/tutorials/recycle.html)
- [Multi-Threading in PHP with pthreads](https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/6437782)
- [Easy pthreads Pools](https://gist.github.com/krakjoe/9384409)

A call to [`get_class_methods()`](http://php.net/get_class_methods) reveals that both classes implement the same methods and [`get_parent_class()`](http://php.net/get_parent_class) returns `FALSE` for both.

At the moment I'm assuming that `Stackable` is an alias of `Threaded`. Is that correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$stackable = new Stackable;
var_dump(get_class($stackable));
```

Outputs: string(8) "Threaded"

It seems my assumption was correct.